# What is the following error when I try to deploy kube-batch using helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I downloaded the kube-batch in my local PC. Now, when I try to deploy the kube-batch using helm, I got the following error:

```
Error: customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "podgroups.scheduling.incubator.k8s.io" already exists
It appears after using the helm
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust apiVersion in `/src/github.com/hamikube/kube-batch/deployment/kube-batch/Chart.yaml` to a version Helm accepts (v1 instead of v1alpha1 in this case).
Thought the API should then comply to v1 in order to avoid other errors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201805/discussion-on-answer-by-eohm-what-is-the-following-error-when-i-try-to-deploy-ku).